# Same author same year bibliography issue

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

So I want to submit a paper to **Biostatistics** journal, which has its own Latex template and `\bibliographystyle{biorefs}`. The problem arises when I try to cite two different papers of the same author and the same year. Such references are:

```
@article{kwok1999moderating,
  title={Moderating the outputs of support vector machine classifiers},
  author={Kwok,  James Tin-Yau},
  journal={IEEE Transactions on Neural Networks},
  volume={10},
  number={5},
  pages={1018--1031},
  year={1999},
  publisher={IEEE}
}
@inproceedings{kwok1999integrating,
  title={Integrating the evidence framework and the support vector machine.},
  author={Kwok, James Tin-Yau},
  booktitle={ESANN},
  volume={99},
  pages={177--182},
  year={1999}
}
```

I have tried using `\cite` and `\citep`, but both of them produce ***(Kwok, 1999,?)*** as a result, instead of ***(Kwok, 1999a,1999b)*** or ***(Kwok, 1999a,b)***, which is what I want to obtain.

Any idea of how to solve it? Thanks a lot.

**Edit:** Here you can find an example in Overleaf ([link](https://www.overleaf.com/read/xbwjdtszngrk)).

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) it might be an idea to provide a link to the template and the bibtex file as at least the `biorefs.bst` is not included as standard in LaTeX

Comment: Please consider adding a short example document that we can compile to your question. Please also tell us where we can find your version of `biorefs.bst`

Comment: Here you can see an example in Overleaf: [link](https://www.overleaf.com/read/xbwjdtszngrk)

Comment: This seems to be a bug in `biorefs.bst`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in `biorefs.bst`.

Since it is usually a very bad idea to modify files without renaming them, do rename `biorefs.bst` (e.g. `newbiorefs.bst`) and change line 1079 from

```
label.year write$
```

to

```
sort.year write$
```

Like this:

```
FUNCTION {output.bibitem}
{ newline$
  "\bibitem[" write$
  make.abbr.label write$
  "(" write$
  sort.year write$          % <-- here!!!
  ")" write$
  make.full.label write$
  "]{" write$
  cite$ write$
  "}" write$
  newline$
  ""
  before.all 'output.state :=
}
```

Now the output looks like this:

[image]

You should **absolutely** contact the maintainers about this.